# C++ Iterate over nested Tables in tomlplusplus

Tags: c++, toml

I'm using tomlplusplus to load my toml configuration. So far this works good. But i'm currently struggle to iterate over nested tables (table arrays).
Suppose i have a toml configuration like this:

```ini
[[data]]
name = "Data_One"

[[data]]
name = "Data_two"
```

i tried to iterate over the nested tables like it is mentioned in the Documentation for Arrays but this seems not to work. At least i got some compilation errors.

This is the code that i'm using:

```cpp
int main() {
    toml::table tbl;
    try {
        tbl = toml::parse_file("config.toml");
        std::cout << tbl["data"] << '\n';
        toml::array* pipes = tbl["data"].as_array();
        pipes->for_each([](auto&& ele) {
            std::cout << ele << '\n';
        });

    } catch (const toml::parse_error& error) {
        std::cout << error << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the error i got is saying:

```
error C2338: static_assert failed: 'TOML node visitors must be invocable for at least one of the toml::node specializations: ...
error C3313: 'keep_going': variable cannot have the type 'const void' ...
error C3536: 'keep_going': cannot be used before it is initialized ...
```

Is there a way to iterate of the nested tables? I saw that the `toml::table` supports a `is_array_of_tables()` function but not a `as_array_of_tables()` conversion function.